# jQuery datepicker value of day in future

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to compare two days and return an alert, if the startdate is higher than the enddate. I don't know why, but if I choose 19.04.2016 as the startdate and 01.05.2016 as the enddate, I receive the alert.

```
var main = function() {
              var date1 = "";
              var date2 = "";
              $('h1').click(function() {
                  $('h1').remove();
           })

$('#date-start').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function(date) {

        var startdate = $('#date-start').datepicker('getDate');
        $('#date-end').datepicker('option','minDate',startdate);
    }
})
$('#date-end').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
})

$('#btn').click(function() {
    date1 = $('#date-start').val();
    date2 = $('#date-end').val();

    if (date1 > date2) {
        alert("Beginn muss vor dem Ende liegen");
        $('#date-start').css("border-color","red");
        $('#date-end').css("border-color","red");
    }
    if (date1 == "") {
        alert("Bitte alle Felder ausfüllen");
        $('#date-start').css("border-color","red");
        $('#date-end').css("border-color","red");
    }

    document.getElementById("compare-date-text1").innerHTML = date1;
    document.getElementById("compare-date-text2").innerHTML = date2;
})
}

$(document).ready(main)
```

Can you figure out why?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `date1` and `date2` you get string, not Date.

For get Date from datepicker you can use:

```
var date1 = new Date($('#date-start').datepicker('getDate'));
var date2 = new Date($('#date-end').datepicker('getDate'));
```

Then you can compare:

```
if (date1 > date2 ){.........}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the dates from the `datepicker` you need to:-

```
date1 = $('#date-start').datepicker("getDate");
date2 = $('#date-end').datepicker("getDate");
```

you are getting them back as strings to compare instead of dates.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the date *strings*. Therefore, the string **"19.04.2016"** is greater than **"01.05.2016"**. If you format the strings in the Datepicker ISO 8601 [format](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats) **"yy-mm-dd"**, then the strings should compare correctly. The better way is to call `getDate` like the others have suggested.